# Adjusting tick frequency in tick-based simulation in C

Tags: c, time, frequency

I am writing a small simulation in C and I want certain things to occur *N* times every second.

Currently I have the following code:

```
// Equal to 1 / N
struct timespec tick_period = (struct timespec){sec, nsec};

...

for(;;) {
    tick();
    nanosleep(&tick_period, NULL);
}
```

Now this code doesn't take into account the amount of time that it takes to run the `tick` method so gradually the number of ticks per second will skew a little bit.

I would like to accomplish two things:

- To run `tick` *N* times per second without any skew.
- If running `tick` takes so much time that the computer is unable to cope with running it *N* times per second, having some way to adjust the frequency of the tick.

Is there a well known/accepted way of accomplishing these things?

Comment: What system/environment?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8 using standard C and UNIX libraries. No need to worry about Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately the standard unix way (POSIX timers) isn't available on Mac OS X.

Comment: Oh. That is most unfortunate. Is it not part of the UNIX standard?

Comment: It definitely is, but Apple doesn't appear to care about that. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clock_gettime()` to get your start time and then add `tick_period` to it on each cycle.  Then compute the delta to sleep just before each `nanosleep` (or use some other mechanism that lets you sleep until an absolute time).  This will have jitter (especially if your Linux system's clock granularity isn't very good) but it won't have long-term error.

For better results use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`.  This will require using `clock_nanosleep` but has the advantage that you can then use the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag and sleep until your cumulative absolute time.

Update for OSX:  You can use `gettimeofday()` instead of `clock_gettime()` with the added annoyance of converting from `timeval` to `timespec` yourself.  Then you can compute the deltas and sleep with `nanosleep` as before.  It's possible that OSX is still laboring under ancient sleep granularity of HZ, or 10ns.  That will lead to a lot of jitter, but again the overall average will be right.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the type of solution I'm looking for, thanks. Unfortunately none of this is available on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Ben Jackson - good answer for UNIX/Linux.  The OP did not see fit to mention the OS 'til later.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a standard method, but this is a method I have used.

In a nutshell, determine an interval period for your framerate and advance a virtual clock according to this interval. Each frame, determine how much time it took to complete the "work". Subtracting work time from your frame interval tells you how long you need to sleep to reach the next interval.

This by itself will provide the "tick N times per second without skew". It is self correcting, so if you fall behind occasionally, it will speed up when the workload is lighter until it catches up.

If you want to adjust the frame rate to match the workload, just examine the idle time and adjust the interval accordingly.

The code is a small program that demonstrates this. It runs on Linux, I don't know about OS X. I chose 1/2 second intervals because you can watch it run and see whether the timing looks smooth.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/* frame interval is in microseconds */
#define INTERVAL  500000
/* use a variable so it is adjustable */
int interval = INTERVAL;
int ideal = 0;

struct timeval start; /* start time */
void init_time()
{
    gettimeofday(&start, 0);
    wait((1000000 - start.tv_usec));
    gettimeofday(&start, 0);
    ideal = start.tv_usec; /* initialize ideal time */
}

int get_time()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    tv.tv_sec -= start.tv_sec; /* normalize to start time */
    int usec = (tv.tv_sec * 1000000) + (tv.tv_usec);
    return usec;
}

int wait(int usec)
{
    struct timespec ts = { 0, usec * 1000 };
    if (nanosleep(&ts, 0) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: nanosleep interrupted\n");
    }
}

void dowork()
{
    wait((rand() % 5) * 100000); /* simulated workload */
}

void frame()
{
    dowork(); /* do your per-frame work here */

    int actual = get_time();
    int work_time = actual - ideal; /* elapsed time in dowork() */
    int idle_time = interval - work_time; /* idle delay to next frame */

#ifdef ENABLE_VARIABLE
    if (idle_time < 0) {
        /* OPTIONAL: slow frame rate 10% if falling behind */
        interval -= idle_time;
    } else if (interval > INTERVAL) {
        /* OPTIONAL: if we slowed down, but now we have idle time, increase
         * rate 10% until we get to our original target rate */
        interval -= (interval - INTERVAL)/10;
    }
#endif

    if (idle_time > 0) {
        /* sleep for the idle period */
        wait(idle_time);
    }

    printf("FRAME: time %10d (work %10d, idle %10d)\n",
        ideal, work_time, idle_time);

    ideal = ideal + interval;
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    init_time();
    /* simulate 50 frames */
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
        frame();
}
```